# VS code not able to detect or run flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I was doing a project using flutter in vs code and all of a sudden after a shutdown vs code is not [This error shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbA60.png)

The flutter doctor command shows no problem too.
[doctor summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/midoO.png)

Comment: you can try https://fvm.app/. This will help you in the long run.

Comment: Try installing the Flutter plugin again in VSCode. It may be corrupted. `File -> Preferences -> Extensions`

Answer (score 5):

Uninstall and reinstall Dart Flutter Extension sir

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit late to reply but if anyone runs into this problem this fixed it for me.

This happens because maybe **VS Code** can’t find **Path** to **Flutter SDK**.

You can set the path in the VS Code `settings.json` file in `dart.flutterSdkPath`:

[image]

In my case it was to add the `/bin` folder in the path.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

***VS Code** Can’t Find **Path** to **Flutter SDK***

1 - Check flutter and dart extension in VS Code

2 - Press `Ctrl + shift + p` search for flutter SDK, select flutter change SDK, and select auto-detect

3 - Press `Ctrl + shift + p` to search for flutter, then select flutter doctor from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Though you installed and flutter doctor worked well you need to install the extensions in order to work with flutter in VS code environment.

- install Flutter + Dart extensions from the extension tab

Answer (score 0):

Normally this problem occurs because there is more than one reference in the **vs-code** **path** on your system, in an Ubuntu-type distro it may be that there is an installation of **vs-code** in **snap** and **apt**, a solution would be to check if there is an installation of **vs-code** in **snap** and remove it: `sudo snap list code && sudo snap uninstall code`.